# PHP will echo $_POST data, but won't let me store it

Tags: php, forms, post

Okay, weird problem. I have the following php code:

```
<?php

$identifier = $_POST['DEPT'];

function displaydata(){
  return $identifier;
}

?>

HTML CODE HERE

<?php echo displaydata(); ?>
```

This results in a blank page. However, when I replace

```
function displaydata(){
  return $identifier;
}
```

with

```
function displaydata(){
  return $_POST['DEPT'];
}
```

it accurately prints out the requested info.

Any clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 7):

You need to declare `global $identifier` in your function. PHP doesn't automatically look in the global scope for undefined variables outside of the superglobals.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Ahhh, that fixes everything! Thanks!

Comment: Quick follow up. I know that

global $var;
$var = SOMEDATA;
 is okay.

Will:
global $var = SOMEDATA
work?

Comment: No, the global statement needs to be on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have **two $identifier variables**. One is a local variable of displaydata(). The other $identifier, that is assigned the value of $_POST is outside the scope of the displaydata() function.

However $_POST is a **[superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)**. This means it is always available in all scopes. This is why this works:

```
<?php
function displaydata(){
    return $_POST['DEPT'];
}
?>
```

If you want to pass information to the local variables inside of `displaydate`, then use an argument:

```
<?php
displaydate($_POST['DEPT']);

function displaydata($identifier){
    return $identifier;    
}
?>
```

Although, in this case the scope of displaydata includes $_POST, since $_POST is a superglobal.

Answer (score 1):

As above said, make identifier variable global, or better yet pass $identifer as a parameter to the function.  Globals in my experience make for hard debugging in larger applications. 
Generally speaking, there is usually a better approach than to just toss a global around.

Answer (score 1):

$identifier is in the local scope

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $identifier = $_POST['DEPT'];

    function displaydata($idefier){
      return $idefier;
    }
    displaydata($identifier);
    ?>
```

try this one. You have to pass the value to the function or declare $identifier as global